# In an N*M matrix, what is maximum possible number of disconnected components?

Tags: matrix, graph, max, connected-components

It is when for a given cell v, all the cells in right, left, up, down and diagonal directions are considered a neighbour.

Comment: `(n+1)/2 * (m+1)/2` (integer division)